# 2 level css menu that resizes the height of div

Tags: css, menu, navigation, resize

I have the following code. As you will see, there are two divs, one above the other. The first one (red) contains the navigation, and the second one (orange) would normally contain some content. The navigation is on two levels. The first level of navigation will always be active, but the level 2 will only be active as long as we are on the page "menu 3". That means our div that contains the navigation will get higher when level 2 is active. Any idea of how can I get that would be appreciated. I attached an image with the visual explanation. Here is the visual explanation: http://s2.postimg.org/c9u7afy8p/example.jpg

```
<div id="first">
  <ul id="level1">
    <li>menu 1</li>
    <li>menu 2</li>
    <li>
      menu 3
      <ul id="level2">
        <li>menu 3.1</li>
        <li>menu 3.2</li>
        <li>menu 3.3</li>
        <li>menu 3.4</li>
      </ul>
    <li>menu 4</li>
    <li>menu 5</li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="second"></div>

/*CSS*/

#first{
  background:red;
}
#second{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background:orange;
}
ul li{
  display:inline;
  padding-left:30px;
}
ul li ul{
  display:none;
}
ul li:hover ul{
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the style of your level 2 navigation, i.e. the dropdown menu, to `position: absolute` and then set its background color to `red`. This won't increase the height of the `<div>` containing your menu when you will be viewing the dropdown menu, like this:

```css
#first{
  background:red;
}
#second{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background:orange;
}
ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left:30px;
}
ul li ul{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;  
  background: red;  
  padding-left: 0px;
}
ul li ul li{
  display: block; 
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}
ul li:hover ul{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
  <ul id="level1">
    <li>menu 1</li>
    <li>menu 2</li>
    <li>
      menu 3
      <ul id="level2">
        <li>menu 3.1</li>
        <li>menu 3.2</li>
        <li>menu 3.3</li>
        <li>menu 3.4</li>
      </ul>
    <li>menu 4</li>
    <li>menu 5</li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

Comment: The second div (orange) should go down together with the resizing of the navigation (red div), and I should be able to click the level 2 menus. Now the level 2 navigation disappears after I am no longer with the mouse on level 1.

Comment: @dj_andrew Do you want it to look how it does in the image whose link you've posted above?

Comment: Hello, I've uploaded another picture to be more exact. (http://s18.postimg.org/pubz3wspl/example2.jpg) As you can see, there are two level menus. The second one won't show up all the time, and the slider that is under it should go up a bit in order to fill the blank space. Thanks for your help.